# ¿Cómo convertir un archivo excel adjunto en un correo a una hoja de Google Sheets desde Apps Script?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail, blob

Estoy intentando crear una función que extraiga un archivo de excel que venga adjunto en un correo de Gmail específico y luego, ya sea convertirlo a un Spreadsheet, o insertarlo como una nueva hoja dentro de un Spread existente. Hasta el momento solo he logrado leer el correo por su asunto y remitente y extraer el archivo de excel adjunto.

Lo que necesito es el fragmento de código que me permita convertir o insertar el excel en una hoja de sheets.

***Nota:*** Estuve investigando y al parecer se puede hacer creando un Blob a partir del excel; además, también vi que se podría lograr con la biblioteca de SheetsJS, pero no he logrado el resultado deseado con ninguno de estos métodos.

Dejo el código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
function traerCorreos(){
    const carpetaMesId = "id de mi carpeta";
    var carpetaMes = DriveApp.getFolderById(carpetaMesId);
    const recibidos = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
    recibidos.forEach(recibido => {

        const correo = recibido.getMessages()[0];
        if(correo.isUnread()){
  
            const asunto = correo.getSubject();
            const remitente = correo.getFrom();

            if(asunto.includes('Cadena del asunto') && remitente.includes('correo del remitente'){

                const archivo = correo.getAttachments()[0];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

¡De antemano, gracias por su atención!

Answer (score 1):

¡Al fin encontré una forma de hacerlo!

Lo dejo aquí por si a alguien le llega a servir la información:

Con el código que llevaba hasta el momento, guardaba en la variable 'archivo' el excel que venía adjunto en el correo (en formato blob). Ya con este blob es posible insetar el archivo en google Drive convirtiéndolo al mismo tiempo a un GOOGLE_SHEETS. Para ello, se debe activar la API Drive y utilizar su servicio Drive.Files.insert(object, blob, options).

Nota: La API Drive se activa en el panel izquierdo del editor Apps Script donde dice 'Servicios'.

El código completo me quedó así:

```
function traerCorreos(){

    //Datos de la carpeta donde se va a guardar el nuevo archivo GOOGLE_SHEETS
    const carpetaID = "*id de la carpeta*";
    var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById(carpetaID);

    //Obtener toda la bandeja de entrada
    const recibidos = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

    //Iterar a través de cada correo obtenido
    recibidos.forEach(recibido => {

        //Guardar solo los elementos correspondientes a correos del arreglo de recibido
        const correo = recibido.getMessages()[0];

       //Validar si el correo no ha sido leído aún 
       if(correo.isUnread()){
  
           const asunto = correo.getSubject(); //Obtener asunto del correo
           const remitente = correo.getFrom(); //Obtener el remitente del correo

           //Validar si el asunto y remitente coinciden con el correo que estamos buscando
           if(asunto.includes('*ASUNTO DEL CORREO*') && remitente.includes('*REMITENTE DEL CORREO*'){

               //Obtener el archivo de excel adjunto
               const archivo = correo.getAttachments()[0];
    
               //Crear un objeto con las características del nuevo archivo
               var nvaHCG = {
                   title: archivo.getName(), //Nombre del nuevo archivo
                   mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS //Tipo de extensión del nuevo archivo
               }

               //Convertir e insertar el nuevo archivo en Google Drive
               var sheets = Drive.Files.insert(nvaHCG, archivo, {convert:true});
    
               var sheetsID = sheets.getId(); //Obtener el ID del nuevo archivo
    
               //Obtener el archivo por el ID como un elemento google drive
               var archivoSheets = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetsID);

               //Mover el elemento (archivo) a la carpeta deseada
               archivoSheets.moveTo(carpeta);

           }
       }
    });
}
```